# How to set li element positioning that has a parent with absolute position inside a container using horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement a custom navigation menu, in which for a mobile-responsive design, I decided to use a horizontal-scrolling feature on the nav menu container to display the main items (horizontally). These items have sub-items that are displayed vertically (like in a list).

After adding the horizontal scroll, scrolling to the right from its original position causes the sub-items, which displays when hovering over its parent item, to move further right, thereby making it unaligned with its parent.

I've tried adding js code that calculates distance based on the scroll percentage and adjust the sub-items to better align with its parent but im getting varying results.

[Here is my code so far](https://codepen.io/qwirkyrabbit/pen/maGEQP):

```js
// $('.menu-container').scroll(function(){
//     var scrollPercentage = 100*this.scrollLeft/this.scrollWidth/(1-this.clientWidth/this.scrollWidth);
//     console.log(scrollPercentage.toFixed(2));
//     $(".menu > ul > .page_item_has_children > .children").css("margin-left", 100 / (-1.55 * scrollPercentage.toFixed(2)));
// });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text|Libre+Franklin');
body {
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
  /*   font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif; */
}


/***** Start: Forms *****/

.searchform {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/***** End: Forms *****/


/***** Start: Navigation *****/


/*** Start: Menus ***/

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.menu-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.menu-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  /*   max-width: 15rem; */
  /* width: 8rem; */
  /* Adjust this value depending on the longest length of the navigation menu's main link items */
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu>ul>.page_item_has_children>.children {
  padding: 2rem 0 0 0;
}

.menu li li {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
}

.menu li {
  /*   background: #000; */
}

.children {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.children a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.children .page_item_has_children .children {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0rem;
  left: 15rem;
  /* Adjust this value depending on the longest length of the navigation menu's sub-items */
}

.children>li {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  height: 4rem;
  /* Adjust this value depending on the height of the navigation menu's sub-items */
}

.children .page_item_has_children .children>li {
  /*left: 1rem;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
}

li:hover>.children>li {
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 25rem;
  width: 15rem;
}


/*** End: Menus ***/


/***** End: Navigation *****/


/***** Start: Media *****/

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  /*** Start: Searchform *****/
  /*** End: Searchform ***/
  /*** Start: Menus ***/
  /*** End: Menus ***/
}


/***** End: Media *****/
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/front-page">Front Page</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="page_item_has_children">
        <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about">About The Tests</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-image-alignment">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
          <li class="page_item_has_children">
            <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-markup-and-formatting">Page Markup And Formatting</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-markup-and-formatting/formatting-content-with-images">Formatting Content with Images</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item_has_children">
            <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/clearing-floats">Clearing Floats</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/clearing-floats/clearing-floats-part-1">Clearing Floats Part 1</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/clearing-floats/clearing-floats-part-2">Clearing Floats Part 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item_has_children">
            <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-with-comments">Page with comments</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-with-comments/this-page-is-served-with-at-least-10-comments">This Page Is Served With at Least 10 Comments using Disqus</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/about/page-with-comments-disabled">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item_has_children">
        <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1">Level 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li class="page_item_has_children">
            <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2">Level 2</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li class="page_item_has_children">
                <a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2/level-3">Level 3</a>
                <ul class="children">
                  <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2/level-3/level-4">Level 4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2/level-3a">Level 3a</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2/level-3b">Level 3b</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2a">Level 2a</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/level-1/level-2b">Level 2b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/lorem-ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/page-a">Page ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="https://MidniteDev-Development.000webhostapp.com/page-b">Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="container-1">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" /><i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is the expected results during scrolling, no matter how far right it reaches:

```
> Parent item > Parent item > Parent item
              > child item
              > child item
              > child item
```

And this is what i'm getting:

```
> Parent item > Parent item > Parent item
                 > child item
                 > child item
                 > child item
```

To better see what I mean, try resizing the browser when looking at the menu to under 1200px.

Comment: rather sharing link, kindly paste code here on SO, as this will be helpful to others

Comment: Thanks for sharing the question on stackoverflow. Please read this article on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part: `Help others reproduce the problem` for more information on why you shouldn't *just* post a link to your live example. Good luck!

Comment: @AkashDubey the post shows the code snippet though even as the link is included. It's probably the default behavior of SO.

Comment: @StephanT. Thanks for editing my answer, I didn't realize you included the code snippet in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this piece of jquery code on my project which calculates scroll value based on its displacement:

```
$('.menu-container').scroll(function() {
      var menuContainerScrollVal = $(".menu-container").scrollLeft();
     $(".menu > ul > .page_item_has_children >.children").css("margin-left", -menuContainerScrollVal); 
    });
```

This solved my problem and got me the expected solution.